# DDMS Can't start up on Mac OS

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, android-ndk, ddms

I run the monitor file in android ndk folder. But it can't start successfully.

```
java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)
```

The error info is

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2021-01-04 14:48:43.400
>
> !MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
>
> STACK 0
>
> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start()
> of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:225)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch(Framework.java:656)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:274)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)  at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)     at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438) Caused by:
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.setResolved(PackageAdminImpl.java:384)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.setResolvedBundles(PackageAdminImpl.java:658)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start(SystemBundleActivator.java:67)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
> ... 12 more Root exception: java.lang.NullPointerException  at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.setResolved(PackageAdminImpl.java:384)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.setResolvedBundles(PackageAdminImpl.java:658)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start(SystemBundleActivator.java:67)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:225)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch(Framework.java:656)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:274)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)  at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)     at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)

Comment: There is a null pointer exception lurking beneath all the turtles.

Comment: what should I do to solve this problem?